# Html li items to show on a single row each

Tags: css

I cant see how or where the CSS is making these items show in two columns.
i just want them on a single line (full width) each, web tools does not show anything strange with the css, any ideas\quick fix?

```
   #demoOne li { float:left;display: inline  !important;border: #336699 solid 1px;background: lightblue;}
<ul id="demoOne">
<li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add this as well #demoOne input  { float: none}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
display:block
```

rather than

```
display:inline
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `float:left` and `display:inline` use `display:block` and they won't be displayed in two columns

btw. everything with `float:left` has `display:block` so I don't know what you were trying to achieve with that `display:inline!important` :)

Answer (score 0):

for the single line i recommend using the

display:box

For chrome n safari use display:-webkit-box
For opera use display:-o-box
For forefox use display:-moz-box
For ie use display:-ms-box